# match Float number inside string with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a float number after a specific word with regex in java , but I am only getting it when there is nothing between the word and the float number , but I want to get it even there are white spaces any other characters and new lines new lines .

Here the regex that I made :

```
(?<=TOTAL)([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)
```

Example :

> 69003 LYON 03 ejuodnid 04 72.84.75.20 affm groa TICKET FACTURE 361203-
> SEPHORA EYE PALET LIG PALE 29991 14.99 Sephora Collection -Prix 392729
> SEPHORA CINESCOPE
> 16.501 328451- SEPHORA THE MASC BIG MASC goe( 6.99193.49 P Sephora Co11ection Prix 347597SEPHORA LING GRENADE NG 25 i5.99 1) 2.99 Sephora
> Collect1o0 PriX adoy (30 00 1o)o 6.00 oniop20% achats Black Mars 2019
> 451087 OFFRE 20%ACHATS
> 15.00 MASC
> 16.50
> 3.50
> 3.00 N'2
> 24.00 VPBLA
> 0.00 tnoe 0001* 1eepom TOTAL       EUR
> 62.00

Comment: Please post some sample data

Comment: Just use: `(?s)\bTOTAL\b.*?([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` and get group#1

Comment: *FYI:* The full regex for matching a floating-point number is shown in the javadoc for [`Double.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the question as that you want to extract the first float number after a certain word, no matter what is in between.
A non-greedy wildcard will simply do that for you.

`(?<=TOTAL).*?([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)`

Comment: No, it's not valid. :) There was a typo while editing, I have changed it back now.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\bTOTAL\b[\s\S]*?([+-]?\d*\.?\d+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/0ryQ4h/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TOTAL                    'TOTAL'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all but \n,
                           \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [+-]?                    any character of: '+', '-' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Java code:

```
String regex = "\\bTOTAL\\b[\\s\\S]*?([+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+)";
String string = "69003 LYON 03 ejuodnid 04 72.84.75.20 affm groa TICKET FACTURE 361203- SEPHORA EYE PALET LIG PALE 29991 14.99 Sephora Collection -Prix 392729 SEPHORA CINESCOPE 16.501 328451- SEPHORA THE MASC BIG MASC goe( 6.99193.49 P Sephora Co11ection Prix 347597SEPHORA LING GRENADE NG 25 i5.99 1) 2.99 Sephora Collect1o0 PriX adoy (30 00 1o)o 6.00 oniop20% achats Black Mars 2019 451087 OFFRE 20%ACHATS 15.00 MASC 16.50 3.50 3.00 N'2 24.00 VPBLA 0.00 tnoe 0001* 1eepom TOTAL EUR 62.00";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result: `62.00`